# Find the shortest possible unique keys

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, associations

**1. Problem statement**

Given a certain rectangular matrix I want to scan its rows from left right to find equally sized sequences. These sequences should be as short as possible and unique, so that they can be used as `Keys` to associate the remaining row members. A `FirstShortestUncommonSequence`, so to speak.

**2. Test data**

```
list =
  {{2, 4, 1, 7, 1, 4, 1},
   {1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 4, 0},
   {1, 4, 1, 7, 3, 5, 1},
   {2, 4, 1, 7, 4, 5, 0},
   {1, 1, 1, 7, 5, 5, 3}}
```

**3. Example code**

The following code is terrible (it doesn't even have an exit clause), and I only show it to give some examples.

```
CreateKeys[list_?MatrixQ] :=
 Module[{p},
  p =
   First @ FirstPosition[True]@
     Table[
      Length @ DeleteDuplicates[#] == Length[#] & [list[[All, ;; i]]],
      {i, Length @ First @ list}];
  
  If[NumberQ[p],
   AssociationThread[list[[All, ;; p]] -> list[[All, p + 1 ;;]] /. {a_} :> a],
   p]]
```

**4. Examples of expected result**

```
CreateKeys @ list
```

should give

```
<|{2, 4, 1, 7, 1} -> {4, 1},
 {1, 2, 3, 7, 2} -> {4, 0},
 {1, 4, 1, 7, 3} -> {5, 1},
 {2, 4, 1, 7, 4} -> {5, 0},
 {1, 1, 1, 7, 5} -> {5, 3}|>
```

o

```
 CreateKeys[{{1, 1, 4}, {2, 1, 5}}]
```

<|1 -> {1, 4}, 2 -> {1, 5}|>

o

```
CreateKeys[{{1, 1, "a", "b"}, {1, 5, "a", "d"}}]
```

<|{1, 1} -> {"a", "b"}, {1, 5} -> {"a", "d"}|>

and, if no unique keys can be found,

```
CreateKeys[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

"NotFound"

**5. Question**

How can this problem be solved in a functional and efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Association@(Rule @@@ (TakeDrop[#, 
       First@FirstPosition[MapThread[DuplicateFreeQ[{##}] &, list], 
         True]] & /@ list))

(* <|{2, 4, 1, 7, 1} -> {4, 1},
     {1, 2, 3, 7, 2} -> {4, 0},
     {1, 4, 1, 7, 3} -> {5, 1},
     {2, 4, 1, 7, 4} -> {5, 0},
     {1, 1, 1, 7, 5} -> {5, 3}|> *)
```

Maybe more efficient for long sub-lists of `list`:

```
n = 1;
While[Not@DuplicateFreeQ[list[[All, 1 ;; n++]]]];
Association@(Rule @@@ (TakeDrop[#, n - 1] & /@ list))
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives all expected results and is astonishingly short

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[keyLength, shortestDistinctPrefixKeys]

keyLength = Module[{k = 0}, Until[DuplicateFreeQ[#[[All, ++k]]]]; k] &;

shortestDistinctPrefixKeys[lst_?DuplicateFreeQ] := 
   Map[Apply[Rule] @ TakeDrop[#, keyLength @ lst] &] @ lst

shortestDistinctPrefixKeys[_] = {};
```

***Examples:***

```
shortestDistinctPrefixKeys @ list
```

> ```
>  {{2, 4, 1, 7, 1} -> {4, 1},   
>   {1, 2, 3, 7, 2} -> {4, 0},   
>   {1, 4, 1, 7, 3} -> {5, 1},   
>   {2, 4, 1, 7, 4} -> {5, 0},   
>   {1, 1, 1, 7, 5} -> {5, 3}}
> ```

```
shortestDistinctPrefixKeys @ {{1, 1, 4}, {2, 1, 5}}
```

> ```
>  {{1} -> {1, 4}, {2} -> {1, 5}}
> ```

```
shortestDistinctPrefixKeys @ {{1, 1, "a", "b"}, {1, 5, "a", "d"}}
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1} -> {"a", "b"}, {1, 5} -> {"a", "d"}}
> ```

```
shortestDistinctPrefixKeys @ {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[sKeys]

sKeys = Replace[#, 
  {x__, y___} /; DuplicateFreeQ[#[[All, ;; Length @ {x}]]] :> {x} -> {y}, 1] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
sKeys @ list
```

> ```
> {{2, 4, 1, 7, 1} -> {4, 1},   
>  {1, 2, 3, 7, 2} -> {4, 0},   
>  {1, 4, 1, 7, 3} -> {5, 1},   
>  {2, 4, 1, 7, 4} -> {5, 0},   
>  {1, 1, 1, 7, 5} -> {5, 3}}
> ```

```
sKeys @ {{1, 1, 4}, {2, 1, 5}}
```

> ```
>  {{1} -> {1, 4}, {2} -> {1, 5}}
> ```

```
sKeys @ {{1, 1, "a", "b"}, {1, 5, "a", "d"}}
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1} -> {"a", "b"}, {1, 5} -> {"a", "d"}}
> ```

If the input list `lst` is not duplicate-free, `sKeys` returns `lst`:

```
sKeys @ {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}
> ```

If `{}` is the desired ouput for such inputs, wrap `sKeys` with `ReplaceAll[# -> {}]`:

```
sKeys2 = ReplaceAll[# -> {}] @ sKeys @ # &;

sKeys2 @ {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
createKeys[list_?MatrixQ] := Module[{noDFQ = False (* !DuplicateFreeQ *)}, 
   If[noDFQ, <||> (* Not Found *), 
     AssociationThread[# -> list[[All, (1 + Length@First@#) ;; ]]]] &@
   FoldWhile[Flatten /@ Thread[{##}] &, (noDFQ = ! DuplicateFreeQ@#; noDFQ)&]
     [Map[List, Transpose@list, {2}]]]


testmat = {
    {{2, 4, 1, 7, 1, 4, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 4, 0}, {1, 4, 1, 7, 3, 5, 1}
                          , {2, 4, 1, 7, 4, 5, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 7, 5, 5, 3}}
  , {{1, 1, 4}, {2, 1, 5}}
  , {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}}

createKeys /@ testmat

(*{<|{2, 4, 1, 7, 1} -> {4, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 7, 2} -> {4, 0}, {1, 4, 1, 7, 3} -> {5, 1}
                              , {2, 4, 1, 7, 4} -> {5, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 7, 5} -> {5, 3}|>
, <|{1} -> {1, 4}, {2} -> {1, 5}|>
, <||>}*)
```